# Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-qrscanner does not compile after upgrading to Android API level 33

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to upgrade my cordova application to support Android API 33. I have updated Cordova to version 12 and updated Android SDK to 33.0.2. However, cordova plugin "cordova-plugin-qrscanner" does not compile after this update. It is showing the following error when I tried to build:

[build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwxFL.png)

[online_qrscanner.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Gqh.png)

When I remove this plugin I can compile it. So I am assuming it's a compatibility issue of this plugin. This plugin is critical for my application as it requires scanning of QR code.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `compile` is deprecated. The plugin needs to be upgraded to use `implementation` instead.